Linear Mixed Model Assumption Testing
I'm looking at my eye-tracking data, and I'd like to analyse the following gaze data (fixation duration) with a Linear Mixed Model in JAS.
But I'm not sure if the residuals are (approximately) normally distributed based on the Q-Q plots. Since I finished the initial data cleaning, I'm not sure whether I should further exclude more data. Any advice on this would be very much appreciated.

